# My credential were working previously for AWS s3 on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

This is the rails error I get:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch (The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.):
```

No solution I saw was working.

This is my articles.rb and the environment variables are set both on heroku production server and development local machine:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }
  has_attached_file :attachment,
            :path => 'assets/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename',
            :storage => :s3,
            :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
            :s3_bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
            :s3_permissions => 'public-read-write',
            :s3_protocol => 'http',
            :s3_host_name => 'eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
            :s3_host_alias => 'eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
            :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
            :s3_credentials => { :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                                 :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID'],
                                 :endpoint => 'eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' }

  # Explicitly do not validate
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :attachment
  #validates_attachment :attachment, content_type: { content_type:    'application/x-java-archive'}, size: { in: 0..10.megabytes }
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand why? But I had to add `:url => :s3_domain_url` to the paperclip configuration to make this error disappear. And my `TypeError in ArticlesController#create` is still not working... before I added AWS s3 to my Rails app, it was working fine: Unfortunately without persistent storage in heroku production environment.